# Could not get database metadata for mysql on osx

Tags: mysql, macos, hibernate, jdbc, homebrew

I have a mysql database with 3000 tables, and a hibernate application. It working fine on ubuntu, but on Mac(homebrew) always show  connection errors after

```
ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000319: Could not get database metadata
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

I doubt some setting for mysql need to be change, but do not know which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed after added 'max_allowed_packet=20M' to my.cnf

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your database server isn't responding.

Check the configuration files for hibernate and make sure that it's pointed at the right host for the database.

If you're using localhost, make sure that the mysql server you're running locally is up (`ps` or `mysql` command should help here) and verify that hibernate is either communicating over the UNIX socket, or that you have networking turned on in your local server (since by default it's usually off and required for TCP/IP access, even to localhost).

Comment: I added 'connectTimeout=0&socketTimeout=0' to jdbc url , sometime can connect , but disconnect when running some query.